# Remove an array with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to remove an array from a `JSON` file using Jackson. This is the structure of my JSON file:

```
[  
   {  
      "Lorem Ipsum ":3,
      "Lorem Ipsum ":14.2,
      "Lorem Ipsum ":5.8
   },
   {  
      "thingToRemove":"stuff"
   }
]
```

and this is what I've tried, without effect:

```
for (JsonNode personNode : rootNode) {
  if (personNode instanceof ObjectNode) {
     ObjectNode object = (ObjectNode) personNode;
     object.remove("thingToRemove");
  }
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

Add the code written above the following instruction:

```
jsonFile = rootNode.toString();
```

Comment: For duplicate key names, Jackson only reports the last one it finds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading the content of the file in memory and deserialize into a `JsonNode` data structure with Jackson. This data structure is **in memory**. You'll need to write it back to disk (to the file) after you remove an element.

Comment: Thanks. It does remove the content but not the array itself. The result is `{}`